# Click event handler in Angular directive called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Created directive with click event for click, but click called twice.

`stopPropagation` can't help me

```
angular.module('dod').directive('checkbox', [function () {
    var checkbox = {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function (e) {
                elem.toggleClass('checked');
            });
        }
    };

    return checkbox;
}]);
```

Comment: Where is your directive currently being applied in your html?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to have some html.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the angular way to perform this task either;  you shouldn't ever need to manually adjust the DOM in this manner; this is a task that `ng-class` is designed for.

Comment: I agree with @Claies.  In addition if you are handling DOM events in this manner, generally you need to then call apply in your event handler like so: `elem.on('click', function(){ $scope.$apply( function() { ... code here })});`

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation with DOM the way you shown is not a good idea. It is "not an angular way". 
Since you are trying to toggle the element you are clicking, it looks like you cat try this approach from the angularjs doc:

```
<script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
   </label><br/>
  <tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel.value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>value2 = {{checkboxModel.value2}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D